# Wordpress _x values does not return translation in custom taxonomy menu name

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, translate

I have an issue translating custom taxonomy menu and its items in Wordpress. As other translated values do return translation (ex. custom post values), I can tell, that it is not an syntax or string problem. I have tried also replacig **_x to _** what helped only for returning custom post type values.
Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'sauto_catalog_categories', 0 );

function sauto_catalog_categories() 
{
  $labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Categories', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Category', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category', 'sauto-catalog' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name', 'sauto-catalog' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Category', 'sauto-catalog' ),
  );    

  register_taxonomy( 'product_category', array('sauto_product'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product_category' ),
  ));
}
```

***Is there another way to echo or print translated value in custom taxonomy arguments array?***

Comment: Mighty good question, I have the same problem ..

Answer (score -1):

If you want echo, you use with `_e()` method, if you want just return the string, you can use with `__()` method.

Do not forget to register the text-domain !

For more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: I mentioned before, that i have registered textdomain. It works perfectly. I can't use _e() if i want to use this translation in adding custom tax. arguments via array, i must use __ or _x.